# How to show 3 locations as one?

Tags: forms, mobile, android, multi-selection

I'm working on an application which allows users to search real estate.

One of the app's features will be the ability to search in several (maximum of 3) locations at the same time.

**Problem**
How to show the user all 3 locations that he has chosen on the search/home screen?

**Solution 1**
Show text fields with locations as a vertical carousel. In my opinion this is poor because the user can see only one location at once and he could interpret it as a choice between these locations - as **A location** OR **B location**

[image]

**Solution 2** 
Show all text fields as one huge field.

[image]

Maybe some of you will have better ideas.

Comment: I think it's a great idea for a real estate app, but may I ask why the limit of 3? Does performance suffer with more than 3? If you decide to increase the maximum, it may affect your UI decision.

Comment: You may seriously overestimate the ability of your users to efficiently split attention among three locations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you just limit adding location up to three positions? When maximum is reached the button is dissapeared, so it is natural constraint.
Also I think it is more convenient to display first more specific location part, i.e. street. You can hide part of a city name, it is in user's mind. But street address is more complex to keep in mind.

[image]

**UPDATE**

- If this step is in the middle of the task flow, user have just selected locations and next step is performed immediately, it's no problem just to display "3 locations in Warszaw". Because 1) locations still in user's mind, 2) next step will display search results containing full addresses.
- If the search is not performed immediately, you could use a kind of drop-down box:
  [image]
- Fianlly, if pause lasts over 4-5 minutes or you start next time from this screen, just display all the locations explicitly.

So the short answer is **it depends on task flow specifics**.

Comment: But this is not a case :) Add/remove location is in new activity which is trigerred by click in location textfield. My problem is more about how to show locations informations when user choose maximum number of it. (3)

Comment: @user22513, sorry, I've got it. Answer is updated.

Answer (score 0):

You could just write "3 selected locations" and add an `edit locations` icon to it.

Comment: Thnx, but then user do not see information about locations which he choosed. He must to remember it.

Comment: Add initials...